# Rectangles and combinations.

Tags: combinations, rectangles

A class had 48 students but only half of them had uniforms. During
inspection, they form a 6×8 rectangle, and it was just enough to conceal in its
interior everyone without a uniform. Later, some new students joined the
class, but again only half of them had uniforms. During the next inspection,
they used a different rectangular formation, again just enough to conceal in its interior everyone without a uniform. How many new students joined the
class?

I understood this questions as, with adding more students, now two students will be with uniform and two without; in the rectangle. So, (6+2)x(8+2)=8x10=80 total students.   So, 80-48=32students.   So, Answer=32 new students.   Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint 1.**

People 'inside' the rectangle form another rectangle, but with sides shorter by 2. We also know, that people without an uniform are half of all people, thus the bigger rectangle is two times bigger.

You have to solve then the equation:
$$ab=2(a-2)(b-2)$$
for positive integer $a$ and $b$

Also notice, that pair $(8,10)$ (or $(10,8)$) doesn't satisfy this equation - forming a rectangle $8\times10$ makes, that on the circumference there are $32$ people, not $40(=80/2)$.

**Hint 2.**

To show the uniqueness of the solution you should take a look at the graph of the function $b(a)$

Comment: Thank You @Jaroslaw Matlak.   But, I don't understand how the equation came up.

Comment: @MathTise I've improved my answer.

Comment: Thank You @Jaroslaw Matlak.   I understand now.

Comment: I plotted b(a) = 4(a-2)/(a-4)  But the graph gives a different solution.

Comment: @MathTise I think, that you've looked at the zero place - it's not the point. The graph should tell you, if increasing $a$ will give positive integer $b$.

Comment: Greatly appreciated @JaroslawMatlak ...   Thank You very much.